# My new monitor seems to have a yellowish tint. Is there any way to deal with it?

Tags: display, macbook, colors, external-display

So I bought a new monitor http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LS27D590PS/ZA to connect to my MBA. However it seems to have a quite obvious yellowish tint with its display. I also encountered a similar issue when I bought another one earlier http://www.lg.com/hk_en/monitors/lg-23EA53VQ. On the contrary, the monitor DELL 2312HM which I've been using for a while seems to have more normal colors. I've heard on a forum that this issue is not that rare. Is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: There should be a menu button on the monitor, and at the very least you should be able to adjust the colour temperature, if not the individual colours. If the monitor settings do not yield a satisfactory colour balance and you cannot return it as faulty, then you will need to use the graphics card to make the adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple, cheap, yet pretty inaccurate method would be to go to
System Prefs > Displays > Colour > Calibrate
& work through that as best you can, by eye.

It is not going to be anywhere near as good, though, as to do it properly using a colorimeter. These start at around 80-100 bucks or equivalent & go up to silly money.

You'd be surprised at just how far out of true most monitors are, at default settings. It's very nice to be able to have every screen in the building all showing the same colour.

Personally, I'd say unless you need this for a professional workflow, to print or web etc, then an entry-level one would be just fine. I use a [ColorMunki Smile](http://www.xrite.com/custom_page.aspx?PageID=345) which is fine for my needs - I hate mismatched monitors, but I don't have a professional workflow requirement.

They are all usually cross-platform, Mac/PC, & the Smile can actually be used on smart-phones too, if you really need to.

If you're going to do some Googling & eBaying etc to research one to suit you - avoid the Huey Pro, which used to be fine for entry-level calibration, but no longer works properly on Mac since Mavericks.

Comment: Cool. So that is to say no matter what there should be a way to calibrate the screen to be more normal, instead of no way at all? Because in threads like this one http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-to-fix-slight-yellow-ish-tint-on-lcd-led-monitor.452884002/ I see people just saying they returned it as faulty. However it's a bit tricky in my situation and I'm not sure whether if I get a new one it would be any better.

Comment: Yes, you can always try to get it closer to optimum, even if you do it manually. New screens are often closer than the old CRTs, but even 2 supposedly identical monitors can be slightly different. By eye you can try to match them… but with no external reference, you'll never be certain which is actually right.